# React router POP

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I'm investigating my react application's router actions history, and found that there are many "POP" action that comes right after a "REPLACE" action. I couldn't seem to find more documentation about the "POP" action, what is it? and what does it do?

Is it safe or right to add a validation in my component to validate the `location.action` in my `componentDidUpdate()` life cycle?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Found [this article](https://medium.com/young-coder/a-simple-introduction-to-the-history-api-in-javascript-85b879d3d87e) written by [Matthew](https://medium.com/@prosetech) explaining the History API very well:

**Returning to a previous page**

When you use the `pushState()` method, you also need to think about its natural counterpart, the `onPopState` event. While the `pushState()` method puts a new entry into the browser’s history list, the `onPopState` event gives you the chance to deal with it when the user returns.

To understand how this works, consider what happens if a visitor steps through all the slides in the *Dictionnaire Infernal* example. As each new slide is loaded up, the page adds a history entry. But if the user steps back with the Back button, nothing happens.

To fix this shortcoming, you need to handle the `onPopState` event, which is triggered after every history navigation. (This includes if you use one of the history methods, like `history.back()`, as well as when the user clicks the browser navigation buttons.)

The `onPopState` event provides your code with the state information you stored earlier with `pushState()`.

...

**If you push, you must pop**. The `pushState()` method and `onPopState` event are partners. What you put in with one, you get back with the other.

Answer (score -2):

`POP` is a browser back event action. And why do you want to validate `location.action`?

Comment: I tried logging the redux actions and found there is excessive back and forth of `REPLACE` and `POP` action. I'm still investigating the cause of the issue, but I wanted to know what and why is there two actions happening for one event. Can we make it only one action instead of two? or is it necessary to have the `POP` action?

Comment: You are logging the `location.action` of previous props and current props. So obviously the previous.props' location.action would be `POP`. But still, I'm not sure why do you want to log the redux action.

Comment: I was inspecting the application of redux state changes, and found that there is 400 times state change in 1-2 seconds when I click a button that does router push. So then I try logging what are these 400 times changes, and most of them are these `REPLACE` + `POP` actions (2 times state change), the screenshot is a little bit misleading as that is the other logs from the component. Anyway, my question / confusion is only about the `POP` action. Trying to understand it. Is it intended to be like that? and actually, what does it do?